# Удаление с помощь DELETE IN (SELECT)

Tags: php, sql

Есть запрос 
`mysql_query("DELETE FROM timages WHERE timages.id IN (
              SELECT tholidaysimages.imageid FROM tholidaysimages 
              WHERE tholidaysimages.hotelid=".$hotelid`
В SQL отрабатывает, но в php ни в какую.
Для првоерки ставлю
`mysql_query("UPDATE tholidays set status=0 where id=".$hotelid)`
Все работает, уже не знаю где копать???
Полный код функции:

```
function bookingHolidaysDelete($hotelid){
$result = "error";
try {
    $cn = dbConnect();
        if($hotelid > 0)
        {
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM timages WHERE timages.id IN (
                SELECT tholidaysimages.imageid FROM tholidaysimages 
                WHERE tholidaysimages.hotelid=".$hotelid);
            //mysql_query("UPDATE tholidays set status=0 where id=".$hotelid);

            if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
                $result="done";
            else
                $result="Ошибка sql";
        }
        else
            $result="Не выбрано помещение";
    mysql_close($cn);       
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $result = $e->getMessage();
}
```

return $result;
}

Comment: А скобки в запросе закрывать за вас Пушкин будет? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А так?

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM timages WHERE timages.id IN
  (
    SELECT tholidaysimages.imageid FROM tholidaysimages 
    WHERE tholidaysimages.hotelid = $hotelid
  )
");
```

Comment: Спасибо, я Рак))) 3 дня уже в коде, голова слетает)))) СПАСИБО!!!